# What is Delay Import in PE Files?

Tags: reverse-engineering, portable-executable

While researching about PE files, I came across something called "delay import," but I couldn't understand what it meant.

This structure is stored in the 13th index of the data directory. The RVA stored at this index points to a structure called the Delay Import Table.

I found this structure in winnt.h

```cpp
typedef struct _IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR
{
    union
    {
        DWORD AllAttributes;
        struct
        {
            DWORD RvaBased:1;
            DWORD ReservedAttributes:31;
        } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    } Attributes;

    DWORD DllNameRVA;
    DWORD ModuleHandleRVA;
    DWORD ImportAddressTableRVA;
    DWORD ImportNameTableRVA;
    DWORD BoundImportAddressTableRVA;
    DWORD UnloadInformationTableRVA;
    DWORD TimeDateStamp;
} IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR, *PIMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR;
```

Here is the delay import diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dd96x.png

But i dont know mean of the fields. How works Delay Import and mean of the `_IMAGE_DELAYLOAD_DESCRIPTOR` fields?

Comment: It's imports that are only resolved once the function is actually called - as opposed to when the referencing module is loaded. It cuts down on load time but makes the initial call to each function slightly slower. It also allows for referencing functions that might not actually be there without incurring a load failure. The failure only occurs if the function call is actually made.